# A reusable arraylist created by bufferredReader from txt file. How do it, what is the best way?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, collections, bufferedreader

at the beginning I want to say that I care about the best solution to the problem. Namely, I created a method that retrieves data from a file and then creates a list from it:

```
public List<Klient> bufferedReaderCollection() throws IOException {
            String line;        
    try {
        bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream(fileName), "UTF-8"));

          while((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {

          String[] split = line.split(";"); 
          String nameCompany = split[0].substring(2);
          String adress = split[1]; 
          String phoneNumber = split[2]; 
          String emailAdress = split[3];

          Client k = new Client(nameCompany, adress, phoneNumber, emailAdress);
          bufferedReaderClientLIst.add(k); 
          }

    }catch (IOException e) {


}
    System.out.println(bufferedReaderClientLIst);
    return bufferedReaderClientLIst;

}
```

This method is run by a separate thread. I would like this method to be implemented whenever an operation on the list is performed, and here the problem arises because the thread finishing its work return me an empty list. As a result, for each method of sorting data in the list or searching for data, I must add this code:

```
 bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream(fileName), "UTF-8"));

      while((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {

      String[] split = line.split(";"); 
      String nameCompany = split[0].substring(2);
      String adress = split[1]; 
      String phoneNumber = split[2]; 
      String emailAdress = split[3];

      Client k = new Client(nameCompany, adress, phoneNumber, emailAdress);
      bufferedReaderClientLIst.add(k);
```

I am looking for a solution that will allow me to use the list without giving up threads and adding to each method BufferedReder function. I would like a separate method to do this, and then other methods were responsible for data search etc.. What solution would you apply to this problem? I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Remove your try/catch.  Your method already has `throws IOException` (which is good and correct).  Do not suppress a failure to read the file.  Returning bad data is not doing the calling code any favors.  The caller of the method deserves to know if the file could not be read.

Comment: thanks for the good advice, I will correct it

Comment: Use local variables. Declaring the variables `bf` and `bufferedReaderClientLIst` outside the method will sooner or later produce bugs, if it didn’t already. Use the [try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html).